# How can I open image with encoding cp1251 using PIL library in python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

I have a code which is selecting an image and displaying it on the screen:

```
from customtkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

set_appearance_mode('System')
set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

window = CTk()  # Window
window.geometry("800x520")

def select_image():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(title="Select an image", filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"), ("jpg files", "*.jpg"), ("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"), ("bmp files", "*.bmp"), ("all image files", "*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp")))
    print(filename)
    selected_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    label = CTkLabel(window, image=selected_image).place(x=0, y=0)

image_button = CTkButton(window, text="I", bg_color='white', fg_color='white', hover_color='yellow', width=25, height=25,
                        text_color='black', command=select_image)
image_button.place(x=425, y=10)

window.mainloop()  # Loop
```

After I'm running my code and selecting my image I'm ruining into this problem:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/Downloads/smiling emojipng.png' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 109: character maps to <undefined>
```

I think something wrong is happening with incoding but I'm not sure.

Comment: `askopenfile` doesn't return you a filename. https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image.open()` method receives the file path, and the `filedialog.askopenfilename()` method returns the file path, so you should modify your code like this:

```py
from customtkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

set_appearance_mode("System")
set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

window = CTk()  # Window
window.geometry("800x520")


def select_image():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Select an image",
        filetypes=(
            ("png files", "*.png"),
            ("jpg files", "*.jpg"),
            ("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"),
            ("bmp files", "*.bmp"),
            ("all image files", "*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp"),
        ),
    )
    print(filename)

    selected_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    label = CTkLabel(window, image=selected_image).place(x=0, y=0)


image_button = CTkButton(
    window,
    text="I",
    bg_color="white",
    fg_color="white",
    hover_color="yellow",
    width=25,
    height=25,
    text_color="black",
    command=select_image,
)
image_button.place(x=425, y=10)

window.mainloop()  # Loop
```